# "NaN" is not extracting in .csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nan

My objective is to pass the .xlsx file and convert it into .csv, and parse to  remove special character from .csv and "NaN" should display in empty cell. To do so i am using below code.

If I ran below command on the console followed by #df it shows the NaN in the output. On other side If I run the code, doesn't capture the "NaN" in .csv ?

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\1480587\\Documents\\Chander\\Elastic\\Data\\Dec_Inc_Data.xlsx')
```

Using below version of Python and Pandas.

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.11.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 10
pandas: 0.17.1
nose: 1.3.7
pip: 8.0.2

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\1480587\\Documents\\Chander\\Elastic\\Data\\Dec_Inc_Data.xlsx')
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\1480587\\Documents\\Chander\\Elastic\\Data\\Dec_Inc_Data3.csv')
```

Comment: NaN (Not a Number) is a placeholder. You can use replace if you want to return a string in your csv file: `df.replace(np.nan, 'NaN')`

Comment: @Chris .. after adding df.replace(np.NaN, 'Empty') still same..

Comment: make sure you set df.replace as a variable: `df = pd.read_excel()` `df= df.replace(np.nan,'NaN')` `df.to_csv()`

Comment: Dear @Chris.. Thanks a ton..  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can convert np.nan to string "NaN" in the data frame. But a better and faster way is to give pandas a proper parameter when reading in the excel file, specifying what value should be mapped to nan and what should not.

When you are calling read_excel function, you are using the default value of `na_values` parameter. According to the [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), it converts values `["", "#N/A", "#N/A N/A", "#NA", "-1.#IND", "-1.#QNAN", "-NaN", "-nan", "1.#IND", "1.#QNAN", "N/A", "NA", "NULL", "NaN", "n/a", "nan", "null"]` into np.nan. Therefore, you can pass in your own na_values list without string "NaN" in it, then you will see "NaN" as string in your dataframe.